Global scope, Local scope and an included Library
This script does recognize the Highs and Lows in [0][1][2] with referring to an Pivot-Array from the following library:
https://www.tradingview.com/script/bzIRuGXC-ZigZag/
Is there a possibility to get it into global scope? Because one cannot set bgcolor on local scope.
if zigZag.pivots.size() > 2 
    latestPiv = zigZag.pivots.last()
    previousPiv = zigZag.pivots.get(zigZag.pivots.size() - 2)  // or latestPiv[1]
    prepreviousPiv = zigZag.pivots.get(zigZag.pivots.size() - 3)  // or latestPiv[2]
    log.info("latest {0}", latestPiv.isHigh)
    log.info("previous {0}", previousPiv.isHigh)
    log.info("preprevious {0}", prepreviousPiv.isHigh)
    if latestPiv.isHigh and prepreviousPiv.isHigh
        
    else if not latestPiv.isHigh and prepreviousPiv.isHigh
            
    else
         


On global scope the script doesn't work anymore (without an error)
latestPiv = zigZag.pivots.last()
previousPiv = zigZag.pivots.get(zigZag.pivots.size() - 2)  // or latestPiv[1]
prepreviousPiv = zigZag.pivots.get(zigZag.pivots.size() - 3)  // or latestPiv[2]

backgroundColour = if latestPiv.isHigh and prepreviousPiv.isHigh
    color.new(#6efb9d, 60)
else if not latestPiv.isHigh and prepreviousPiv.isHigh
    color.new(#f2a1af, 60)
else 
    color.new(#bababb, 60)

bgcolor(backgroundColour, title="Conditionally coloured background")

The script should change the bgcolor if there is a higher high than the one before the previous one.
